# Short-hand routes and redirections with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, http-headers, location

I have some resources in my routes file:

```
resources :snippets
resources :pastes
```

Users can access a snippet like this:

```
/snippets/72384
/pastes/ac6Xs28
```

As a short-hand, for tweets, IRC, etc… I want `/s/<id>` to be redirected to `/snippets/<id>`, and `/p/<id>` to `/pastes/<id>`. I want this redirection to use the Location HTTP header and the 301 Moved Permanently HTTP status code.

How am I about to do this? Thanks.

---

<sub>I'm using Rails 3 with WEBrick</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in `routes.rb`

```
match "/s/:id", :to => redirect("/snippets/%{id}")
```

[Here's a nice overview](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) of routing in Rails3.